# Coordinates are different between tkinter and customtkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates, customtkinter

Okay so I have some code that prints out the cursor position on the window whenever i click and move my cursor:

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry("400x400")


def drag(event):
    print(event.x, event.y)

window.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag)

window.mainloop()
```

(so it prints `x=400 y=400` in the bottom right corner)

Now whenever I switch out the window from `tk.TK()` to `ctk.CTk()`, the window visually still has the same size, however the coordinates for x and y go over 400 in both directions (the bottom right corner is now at `x=500 y=500`)

Does anyone know why this is the case or if this doesn't happen for them?

Edit: My system scaling factor is 125% and so customtkinter scales 400x400 to 500x500. To fix any problems I had when for example placing widgets I just need to work with coordinates multiplied by 0.8 or use custom scaling.

Comment: Is your system scaling factor set to 125%?

Comment: Yes... So you mean ctk scales the app to 500x500 px and normal tk doesnt? But visually the window is always the same size...

Comment: It worked for me when using 500x500.

Comment: Yeah it all had to do with the scaling... Since I have 125% scaling on my screen I just needed to work with whatever coordinates * 0.8 and everything is fine